# The normality assumption of t distribution

Tags: distributions, t-distribution

According to the definition of T distribution, the numerator (stand normal distribution) should be independent of the denominator ( chi square distribution).

If the population of the sample is normal distribution, we could prove the sample mean distribution and sample standard derivation distribution are independent. On the hand, if the population is not normal, the independence could not be guaranteed.

However, a lot of T-tests do not assume the normality of population, given that, how could we claim the correctness of T-test?

Comment: 1. When the population is not normal, dependence is certain, since independence of $\bar{x}$ and $s$ characterizes the normal distribution. 2. When you say "a lot of t-tests do not assume normality" ... I can't say I can think of any t-test where the derivation of the test-statistic actually having a t-distribution doesn't rely on normality -- can you give an example?

Answer (score 4):

An assumption of normality is required to derive the t-test, without this assumption the test is not strictly correct. However, tests which are approximately correct are often used because they can give a good estimate.

It's not clear what you are referring to when you say that many t-tests don't assume normality. There are times where we haven't been able to test normality but the limited data we do have doesn't suggest non-normality and our intuition about the distribution of a variable doesn't suggest non-normality. Perhaps you're referring to something like this where we think that normality is a good model but we don't have the data to test that assumption.